# Eliminate Characters In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filenames

I have thousands of file names like this one : LO_Oszukane_169_Pol___MP2_.mpg

Notice how there are 3 underscores after Pol. I need to remove all excess underscores and leave just one.

How could I achieve this in Excel. 
Ive attempted Replace & Substitute

First time using StackOverflow, looking forward to seeing your responses!

Comment: Assume you've tried Ctrl+H? I would have thought that you can select the relevant cells, and then replace ___ with _?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace an arbitrary number of underscores, you can use:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," "))," ","_")`

Assuming that you don't have spaces in your filenames, or if you do, you also want to replace them with underscores, and that you don't have any underscores at the beginning or end that you want to keep. Also note, that it keeps one underscore if it's right before the extension.

Comment: What an unbelievable community! Wish I would of been apart of this a while back...

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace 3 underscore with one. Use `Substitute()` function like below.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"___","_")
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use nested `SUBSTITUTE`-functions for cases with 2 underscores or more.